# Keyboard is not responding before windows boots

Tags: windows, boot, keyboard, reinstall

I have an older desktop computer running Windows XP, and the keyboard doesn't respond at any point before the Windows logon screen is displayed. I need to reinstall Windows, but I can't get to BIOS or to boot manager. I have tried PS/2 and USB keyboards, with no success.

Comment: What brand/model PC?

Comment: Does the keyboard have caps/num/scroll lock lights?  They flash right when the keyboard gets initialized.  I wouldn't put anything past USB, but the PS2 KB should work. This is unusual.

Comment: @gbarry yes it has Caps and NumLock light. it doesn't work until Windows logon windows comes up.

Comment: @packets it has ASRock motherboard.

Comment: Reminder: For PS/2 keyboards the computer usually need a hard-reset after plugging the keyboard in for them to start working.

Comment: @techie007 what do you mean by hard resetting?

Comment: @Dilshod Shut the machine down to power off, then bring it back up again. What model of keyboard? A lot of USB keyboards with N-key rollover aren't recognized by most system's BIOSes, for whatever reason; I've had cases where I needed to plug in a PS/2 keyboard in order to access the BIOS. It's possible that's what you're seeing here, too.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested by [techie007](https://superuser.com/users/23133/techie007) to do "hard reset". I thought a hard reset is taking the battery off and putting it back after a few minutes.

I tried that approach and it works. Now the keyboard is responding before Windows boots.

Comment: Hard reset is resetting your PC .. What you did is CMOS data resetting ..

Comment: @matzone why it is called "hard reset" not just "reset"? Also I was asking I couldn's go to BIOS because my keyboard is wasn't responding. I did reset many times.

Comment: Because there's something called **Soft reset** .. programmatically ..